# Ideal Location For Google Identity Toolkit *.p12 file

Tags: installation, working-directory

I'm working on the Google Identity Toolkit, and have come across what appears to be a riddle.

6. "Put the *.p12 file you just downloaded in a directory of your choosing which is private (you can't let anyone get access to this), but accessible to your web server code."

https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/nodejs

Where should I be placing this file?

Answer (score 5):

Put it in a folder where owner is the server and chmod it to 700, so only the owner can do anything to this folder.

Comment: Amazing! I was thinking it was that simple, but then I feared how simple it may be to hack! Thanks!